# How to apply a jquery animation to a single item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if I worded this correctly, but I am trying to get an item to shake using jquery when you hover over it. I managed to do this, but it shakes whenever you hover over the whole row. I want it to shake ONLY when you hover over the image.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="top-logo" align="center">
    <span class="fa fa-magic fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
$('.top-logo').hover(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('animated'))
  {
      $(this).addClass('animated');
      $(this).stop().effect('shake', {distance:3}, 200);
  }
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('animated');
});
```

Here's the full code: http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/QNZevb

I tried using `display:inline-block` which works but moves the wand to the left while I want it to be centered.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you can't use CSS 3 transitions? It's well supported these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$('.top-logo')
```

by

```
$('.top-logo span')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.top-logo').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('animated');
    $("span", this).stop().effect('shake', {distance:3}, 200);
});
```

`$("span", this)` or `$(this).find("span")` should help since you're trying to target it's child `"span"`